# Mapping integer to object gives error "cannot resolve overloaded constructor"

Tags: scala, oop

I am trying to map integer to object in Scala. I am new to Scala, so I am facing this error "cannot resolve overloaded constructor Item". Please help in resolving this error.

```
object Main extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val listMap1: ListMap[Int, Item] = ListMap(1 -> new Item("mobile", 25000, 1) )

  }
}
```

This error I am getting in this part:

```
new Item("mobile", 25000, 1)
```

This is my class Item:

```
class Item (name: String, price: Int, id: Int){
  def this(name: String, price: Int, id: Int) = {
    this(name,price,id);
  }
}
```

Comment: You have two constrictors which are essentially the same. And the compiler is unable to determine which one to call. - why do you have the second constructor? It is doing nothing. - PS: If you only want to have a plain object that only represents data, you should use a **case class** instead. It will give you a lot of useful things for free.

Comment: Okay thanks @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I removed that ```def this()``` and now the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala, the stuff you put inside the parens when describing your class is the constructor. You then overload it with your `def this...`, and since the have the same signature the compiler can't figure out which one to use.

Note that for situations like this, `case class` provides a lot of nice syntactic sugar. The best way would be to do something like

```
case class Item(name: String, price: Int, id: Int)

val map: Map[Int, Item] = Map[Int, Item](1 -> Item("mobile", 25000, 1))
```